# Countdown timer css analysis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn more about front end web dev and trying to see the page sources of different cool elements i find on the web. I came across [this](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) and was trying to understand how they did the css for the countdown. I only understand parts of the html and I've found where they keep the example:

```
<div class="countdown-container" id="main-example">
```

it would be much clearer if i was able to reproduce it in jsfiddle but i can't. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: you can see the Documentation here: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html

Comment: Why don't you use Firebug and have a look yourself?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this "flip-down" effect you can use css animations or transitions.

Here's a quick look at how to do it with css animations(minus the styling). Transitions will work similarly, but will require a change in state(such as `:hover`).

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip-top {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flip-bottom {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  }
}.top.curr {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: flip-top 2s ease-in infinite;
}

.top.next {
  z-index: 0;
}

.bottom.curr {
  z-index: 0;
}

.bottom.next {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: flip-bottom 2s ease-out infinite;
}
```

Here's an example to play around with: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdXD6gCaHEfsOCR5Osuj?p=preview)

*note: I only prefixed for chrome, so you should open it with chrome or add additional prefixes.*